# Encountered an error while publishing the vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

When publishing your own vscode extension, it prompts "This extension targets Visual Studio 2017 but was not built with an up-to-date VSSDK. Please make sure to update your references and try uploading again. Note: you'll also need to add Prerequisites to your extension.vsixmanifest. ”

I updated all the dependencies and generator-code, but still reported the same error

Answer (score 0):

problem solved! Edited extensions are divided into Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio and Azure Devops. When publishing my extension, I chose to publish the extension of Visual Studio, but my custom extension works on Visual Studio Code!!!

So the solution to the problem is obvious: choose the corresponding editor type when publishing the extension. Here I publish Visual Studio Code and choose her to publish.